# Is it possible to import automation project created in RIDE to Eclipce?

Tags: robotframework

We create Automation project with Robot Framework in both RIDE and Eclipse (with RED) editor. SO is it possible to import automation project created in Ride to RED and vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

Both are editors. In that sense they will load your Robot Framework scripts (.robot/.resource/.py) in the same way. So in this context the answer will be yes.

When you look at the editor functionality then RIDE and RED have different project files that contain editor specific settings. For example the Run definition for RED is different from RIDE. When looking at the editor project context, the answer is No.

So, in short. Robot Framework functionality is supported, editor specific functionality (predictably) not.